# Deploy Build for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, deployment

Our team is working with TeamCity and I am building a deployment system for it. I need to know for a ASP.NET web application what file extensions need to be deployed.

I know I need:

```
.aspx .html .htm .js .css .jpg .png
```

Does anyone know anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be any number of file extensions depending on what your solution is using, but the major ones to check would probably be:

**ASP.NET File Formats:**

`.aspx` `.ascx` `.master` `.asax` `.resx` `.config` `.sitemap` `.skin` `.axd` `.ashx` `.browser`

**HTML & CSS File Formats:**

`.html` `.htm` `.css`

**Image formats:**

`.jpg` `.jpeg` `.gif` `.bmp`

**Other File Formats:**

`.js` `.xml` `.xsl` `.xslt` `.swf` `.log`

Answer (score 1):

You need `.config` for the `web.config` file. As for whatever else you need, it's entirely dependent on your project. We can't really answer this question without knowing the contents of your solution explorer.

You might need `.gif`, `.bmp`, `.swf`, `.log`, or a million other file types.

Comment: Ususally, I _never_ deploy my development configuration to the production system.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @JustinSatyr said about `*.config` extension, you will also most likely need to include room for a `*.asax` extension (for the *global.asax* file) as well as `*.ascx` extension for custom controls.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use msbuild on the Teamcity server? You can then have the solution upon build output all the correct files to a separate directory which then you could copy the entire contents of that directory where you need them

I'll post an example of my NAnt script that we use for this purpose shortly.

```
<property name="solution.directory" value="..\src" />
<property name="solution.file" value="\MySolution.sln" />  
<property name="deploy.source" value="..\buildOutput"/> 
<property name="project.config" value="debug" />
<target name="BuildSolution">
    <echo message="Building ${solution.file}" />
    <exec program="${framework::get-framework-directory(framework::get-target-framework())}\msbuild.exe"
        commandline="${solution.directory}${solution.file} /t:Clean /p:Configuration=${project.config} /v:q"
        workingdir="." />
    <exec program="${framework::get-framework-directory(framework::get-target-framework())}\msbuild.exe"
        commandline="${solution.directory}${solution.file} 
            /t:Rebuild 
            /p:OutDir=..\${deploy.source}\
            /p:Configuration=${project.config} 
            /v:q"
        workingdir="." />
</target>
```

Comment: if you have questions... feel free to ask. I've been doing TeamCity/NAnt/MSBuild deployments for a little over 3 years now.